# Play 2.5 Dependency Injection for play-slick Database Configuration

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am trying to use `play-slick` plugin to interact with a `mySQL` database. Everything works as expected other than a `[warn]` I get everytime I compile the code.

On this line: `val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)`

The warning is: `method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead`.

I have tried adding the inject() method with by defining Configuration using dependency injection but it's not working! How do I use the `Dependency Injection` in the following code so that I don't have to use `Play.current` which has bee deprecated since `Play 2.5`

```
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import scala.concurrent.Future
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


case class User(
    id: Long, 
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String, 
    mobile: Long, 
    email: String
)

class UserTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def mobile = column[Long]("mobile")
  def email = column[String]("email")

  override def * =
    (id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

object Users {

  val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current) //<-- PROBLEM

  val users = TableQuery[UserTableDef]

  def get(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] = {
    dbConfig.db.run(users.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Play current` is deprecated. DBConfigProvider will be injected using guice.

`DatabaseConfigProvider` will be injected into the class `UsersRepo` using guice dependency injection.

Here is the way to do this using Guice and Play 2.5

```
case class User(profileName: ProfileName,
                email: Email,
                createdAt: DateTime,
                id: UserId)

@Singleton
class UsersRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]

  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  private[services] val users = TableQuery[Users]

  def exists(id: UserId): DBIO[Boolean] = {
    users.filter(_.id === id).exists.result
  }


  private[services] class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, UsersTable.name) {
    def profileName = column[ProfileName]("profile_name")

    def id = column[UserId]("user_id", O.PrimaryKey)

    def email = column[Email]("email")

    def createdAt = column[DateTime]("created_at")

    def * = (profileName, email, source, createdAt, id) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

    def emailIndex = index("users_email_index", email, true)
  }

}
```

DB configuration when using `play-slick` in application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-217-243-228.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d344onl0761ji5?user=user&password=pass"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=user
slick.dbs.default.db.password="pass"
```

Comment: how do you call the exists() method from another class?

Comment: @summerNight .... Inject users repo into another class and use it. Read about play 2.5 and guide dependency injection

Comment: @f.g: How can one call the exists() method from another object.. As Injection can not be done with an object.

Comment: @SumitPaliwal inject usersrepo and use its methods

Comment: @SumitPaliwal you cannot use it inside an object . So declare a class and make it singleton using singleton annotation